# C# multiple collections of checkboxes

Tags: c#, checkbox

well I'm just going to get straight to the point, I have 20 checkboxes aligned like so:

[image]

what I'm trying to do is make it so that only 1 checkbox in each column (numbered above) can be checked at one time, I was originally just going to go through each "checked" event and make it so that when one of them is checked it would uncheck the other 3 in the column but I realized that this isn't really practical and it's extremely long because I have 80 checkboxes altogether.

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the correct direction?

Comment: so you want them to function as radiobuttons?? If you change them you just need to set a GroupName for every column

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public class ColumnCheckBox:CheckBox
{
    public int ColumnIndex;
}

void columnCheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int columnIndex = ((ColumnCheckBox)sender).ColumnIndex;
}
```

And then check only checkboxes from that column. Obviously, you would have to have lists of checkboxes `List<List<CheckBox>> CheckBoxList` so that you can do 
`foreach (ColumnCheckBox cb in CheckBoxList(columnIndex))`

Answer (score 0):

Like saul672 said, you should probably just use radio button as that is precisely what they were disigned for. However, if you would still like to implement this with checkboxes because you like square shapes and what not, here's how I would do it:

You have to put the check boxes inside a container that will contain only the check boxes from the same column. Then, add this event to every check box.

```
private void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) sender;
    if (cb.Checked)
    {
        foreach (CheckBox control in cb.Parent.Controls)
        {
            if (control != cb)
                control.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```